# Script in c# for local leaderboard

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, local, leaderboard

I need some help with scripting. I'm making a game in Unity for android.

The idea is to be a simple game without levels, without being demanding, but endearing. It's a single player game. One thing that left is to create leader-board so that players could be able to, after finishing the game, save the name, score, high-score and the results are ranked from highest to lowest.

Since i'm new to game programming, I need help.

I need to create a new script which would create leader board so that players could be able to, after finishing the game, save the name, score, high-score and the results are ranked from highest to lowest

Local, not for server.

Comment: use PlayerPrefs --> http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Comment: Thanks, i would but i don't know how, is there some example how to do it?

Comment: check this out http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/20773/how-do-i-make-a-highscores-board.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetInt.html)

Code looks like this:

```
public class ScoreClass: MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Save.
    void SaveScore(int score) 
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Score", score);
    }

    // Retrieve.
    void PrintScore()
    {
        print(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Score"));
    }
}
```

You can also save floats, to know how check out the [API](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetInt.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use PlayerPrefs to make a leaderboard locally check this link [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

here is a link with an example using PlayerPrefs for local leaderboard [example](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/20773/how-do-i-make-a-highscores-board.html)

Comment: public class Score : MonoBehaviour {
 static int score = 0;
 static int highScore = 0;

 static public void AddPoint() 
 {
  score++;
  if (score > highScore) 
  {
   highScore = score;  
  }
 }

 
 void Start ()
 {
  highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("your high score", 0);
 }

 void OnDestroy ()
 {
  PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("your high score", highScore); 
 }

 void Update ()
 {
  guiText.text = "your score: " + score + "\nyour high score: " + highScore;}
}

Comment: I tried to connect this script with my script but i have to import score and name mannualy...